# reverse proxy legacy server so requests for /style go to correct server

Tags: nginx

We have a large number of very old legacy servers were trying to put a proxy & firewall in front of.  Due to the large number were trying to avoid having to change each server's code and make changes purely from the proxy if at all possible.  We have a proxy which routes to a server based off of the url.  so a request to http://proxy/server1/... would be sent to http://server1/...

Our problem is that the code on the servers will make a request requests for elements at /style and /image etc.  These end up as requests to http://proxy/style instead of http://server1/style.  We don't know which server to route this request to since the server1 part of the URL is stripped off.

We have the following location in nginx:

```
location /foo{
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://server;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

We have two types of legacy servers, one using java servlets and doing most work serverside and one doing a combination of javascript and PHP (did I mention these were old?)

Is there a way to properly redirect these requests, including requests for other resources?

Comment: My guess at a solution (without changing the code that returns `/style` and `/image`) is to add an additional server block listening on 80 with `server_name proxy;` and a `redirect 301 http://server$request_uri;`

Comment: @KeenanLawrence not a bad idea from the information I gave you, i forgot to add another issue.  We have dozens of these servers we redirect from.  We can't just redirect to server because were using the URL of the original request to determine which server to proxy to